# Previous and next in jQuery array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image, src

I have this jQuery code to rotate through images that are stored in an array:

```
index = 0;

$('.thumbnail').click(function(){
    $('.large_view').show();
    $('.large_view').prepend('<img src="'+images[index]+'" width="450px"/>');
});

$('.next').click(function(){
    index = (index==images.length-1)?0:(index+1);
    $('.large_view img').attr('src',images[index]);
});

$('.previous').click(function(){
    index = (index===0)?(images.length-1):(index-1);
    $('.large_view img').attr('src',images[index]);
});
```

But the problem is that because of the `index = 0;`, the same image always shows up, not the one that has been clicked. I need to fix to problem, but still somehow be able to show the previous/next items in my array when `.previous` and `.next` are clicked.

How should this be done?

Comment: What's your relevant HTML?

Comment: Could you put up a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a little helper Javascript function to figure out the "next" and "previous".  Check out the previousIndex and nextIndex methods as defined below.  I used the simplest HTML I could imagine.

I also noticed that you hadn't set the source for the large_image to anything (in the code we saw) so I added line that initalizes the image to the first image on the list.  Try this and see if this is the behavior you were looking for.

```js
var index = 0;

var images = [
  'http://placehold.it/300&text=first+picture',
  'http://placehold.it/300&text=second+picture',
  'http://placehold.it/300&text=third+picture'
];

var previousIndex = function(index, length) {
  if (index <= 0) {
    return length - 1; // cycle backwards to the last image
  } else {
    return index - 1;
  }
}

var nextIndex = function(index, length) {
  return ((index + 1) % length)
};

$('.next').click(function() {
  index = nextIndex(index, images.length);
  $('.large_view img').attr('src', images[index]);
});

$('.previous').click(function() {
  index = previousIndex(index, images.length);
  $('.large_view img').attr('src', images[index]);
});

/** initialize the image on load to the first one */
$('.large_view img').attr('src', images[index])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' class='next'>next</a>
<a href='#' class='previous'>prev</a>
<div class="large_view">
  <img />
</div>
```

Comment: So what should the index be set as? Should it be set at all? Also, the javascript seems to make my image thumbnail disappear...

Comment: I've made edits above.  You still need to initialize index to 0 somewhere (as you were doing).  As for the disappearing thumbnails, I'd forgotten a `-1` in the previous index computation.  I've fixed that above.

Comment: Hmm... it's not working. Also, it doesn't solve the issue of the same image showing up no matter what thumbnail is clicked. Is it possible to just use jQuery? The editor I'm using is technically a debugger, so it won't accept something about the JavaScript code.

Comment: There was another typo in the previousIndex method.  I've replaced the answer with a runnable code snippet that works the way I think you want.  Give it a try.